# How to mock a method which return a value from another method with some parameter. I want to pass my own parameter when Its calling another method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, junit5

```
public int method1(a,b,c){
      //some operation for c
       return method2(a,b,1,3);


//method from another class
public int method2(a,b,g,h){
        return a+b+g+h;
}
```

I want to write test cases for method1. But I want to pass my own parameter to method2 when its calling the same as return

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use *partial mocking* approach.

For example, you have class with 2 methods. *MethodB* is called from *MethodA*.

```java
public class Example {

    public int methodA(int a) {
        return methodB(a);
    }

    public int methodB(int a) {
        return a + a;
    }
}
```

Test with mocking methodB will look like this. Use thenAnswer method to get arguments from invocation and return result based on it

```java
@Test
void sampleTest() {
    Example classUnderTest = Mockito.spy(new Example());

    Mockito.when(classUnderTest.methodA(10)).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
        Integer firstArgument = invocation.getArgument(0);
        return firstArgument * firstArgument;
    });

    assertEquals(100, classUnderTest.methodA(10));
}
```

Keep in mind that it will not work with private and static methods, for these ones use special library powermock etc.

Comment: How to do the same without returning the result. I want the return value based on y parameter

Comment: Check my updated answer for parameter reading

Comment: Can I mock method1 but wanted to get the return value from method2 with different parameter like method2(a,b4,5)